# Ruby optional parameters

Tags: ruby, optional-parameters

If I define a Ruby functions like this:

```
def ldap_get ( base_dn, filter, scope=LDAP::LDAP_SCOPE_SUBTREE, attrs=nil )
```

How can I call it supplying only the first 2 and the last args? Why isn't something like

```
ldap_get( base_dn, filter, , X)
```

possible or if it is possible, how can it be done?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

This isn't possible with ruby currently. You can't pass 'empty' attributes to methods.  The closest you can get is to pass nil:

```
ldap_get(base_dn, filter, nil, X)
```

However, this will set the scope to nil, not LDAP::LDAP_SCOPE_SUBTREE.

What you can do is set the default value within your method:

```
def ldap_get(base_dn, filter, scope = nil, attrs = nil)
  scope ||= LDAP::LDAP_SCOPE_SUBTREE
  ... do something ...
end
```

Now if you call the method as above, the behaviour will be as you expect.

Comment: A little gotcha with this method: e.g. If you're trying to make the default value for `scope` true and you pass in `false`, `scope ||= true` won't work. It evaluates the same as `nil` and will set it to `true`

Comment: is it possible with the current version of ruby, 3 years after this answer?

Comment: @JoshPinter, nice explanation. Basically ||= is not a = b or c, I cringed at seeing `xyz||=true`. It's saying if it's nil, it's always true. If it's true, it's true.

Comment: With everyone saying how bad `scope ||= true` is, I'm surprised that no one has mentioned that the better way to do this is with `scope = LDAP::LDAP_SCOPE_SUBTREE if scope.nil?`. Of course, even that is assuming that `nil` is an invalid value.

Comment: Update to this oldie: An alternative is to use the underscore notation. Unfortunately, it has the same effect as setting the parameter to `nil`. Some may like the notation: `ldap_get(base_dn, filter, _, X)` (note: I do not know (yet) when this was introduced in Ruby. Interesting [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559561/where-and-how-is-the-underscore-variable-specified?lq=1)).

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, the issue raised by Josh is no longer a problem, at least in 2.1.3+ (and possibly older versions).

Comment: @EricPlaton I think that can cause issues if you also use `_` to ignore return values: `_, a = some_method` (not sure how standard this is in ruby but it's common in other languages) because `_` simply acts like a normal variable.

Comment: @sealocal why do you say that? I think it is still an issue in ruby 2.3: `a = false; a ||= true; puts a`

Comment: @sprkysnrkyHonestly, I don't remember and I was probably wrong. I think I misunderstood the point that Josh was making when I first found this Q.

Answer (score 137):

You are almost always better off using an options hash.

```
def ldap_get(base_dn, filter, options = {})
  options[:scope] ||= LDAP::LDAP_SCOPE_SUBTREE
  ...
end

ldap_get(base_dn, filter, :attrs => X)
```

Comment: A common strategy is to have a default options hash and merge in whatever was passed in: `options = default_options.merge(options)`

Comment: I discourage this because the options don't tell you what the method expects or what the default values are

Answer (score 54):

Time has moved on and since version 2 Ruby supports named parameters:

```
def ldap_get ( base_dn, filter, scope: "some_scope", attrs: nil )
  p attrs
end

ldap_get("first_arg", "second_arg", attrs: "attr1, attr2") # => "attr1, attr2"
```

Comment: You can also use a double splat to collect additional undefined keyword arguments.  This is related to this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35259850/160363

Answer (score 3):

It isn't possible to do it the way you've defined `ldap_get`. However, if you define `ldap_get` like this:

```
def ldap_get ( base_dn, filter, attrs=nil, scope=LDAP::LDAP_SCOPE_SUBTREE )
```

Now you can:

```
ldap_get( base_dn, filter, X )
```

But now you have problem that you can't call it with the first two args and the last arg (the same problem as before but now the last arg is different).

The rationale for this is simple: Every argument in Ruby isn't required to have a default value, so you can't call it the way you've specified. In your case, for example, the first two arguments don't have default values.

Answer (score 1):

1) You cannot overload the method ([Why doesn't ruby support method overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373104/why-does-ruby-not-support-method-overloading?lq=1)) so why not write a new method altogether?

2) I solved a similar problem using the splat operator * for an array of zero or more length. Then, if I want to pass a parameter(s) I can, it is interpreted as an array, but if I want to call the method without any parameter then I don't have to pass anything. See *Ruby Programming Language* pages 186/187

Answer (score 0):

Recently I found a way around this. I wanted to create a method in the array class with an optional parameter, to keep or discard elements in the array.

The way I simulated this was by passing an array as the parameter, and then checking if the value at that index was nil or not.

```
class Array
  def ascii_to_text(params)
    param_len = params.length
    if param_len > 3 or param_len < 2 then raise "Invalid number of arguments #{param_len} for 2 || 3." end
    bottom  = params[0]
    top     = params[1]
    keep    = params[2]
    if keep.nil? == false
      if keep == 1
        self.map{|x| if x >= bottom and x <= top then x = x.chr else x = x.to_s end}
      else
        raise "Invalid option #{keep} at argument position 3 in #{p params}, must be 1 or nil"
      end
    else
      self.map{|x| if x >= bottom and x <= top then x = x.chr end}.compact
    end
  end
end
```

Trying out our class method with different parameters:

```
array = [1, 2, 97, 98, 99]
p array.ascii_to_text([32, 126, 1]) # Convert all ASCII values of 32-126 to their chr value otherwise keep it the same (That's what the optional 1 is for)
```

output: `["1", "2", "a", "b", "c"]`

Okay, cool that works as planned. Now let's check and see what happens if we don't pass in the the third parameter option (1) in the array.

```
array = [1, 2, 97, 98, 99]
p array.ascii_to_text([32, 126]) # Convert all ASCII values of 32-126 to their chr value else remove it (1 isn't a parameter option)
```

output: `["a", "b", "c"]`

As you can see, the third option in the array has been removed, thus initiating a different section in the method and removing all ASCII values that are not in our range (32-126)

Alternatively, we could had issued the value as nil in the parameters. Which would look similar to the following code block:

```
def ascii_to_text(top, bottom, keep = nil)
  if keep.nil?
    self.map{|x| if x >= bottom and x <= top then x = x.chr end}.compact
  else
    self.map{|x| if x >= bottom and x <= top then x = x.chr else x = x.to_s end}
end
```

Answer (score -1):

It is possible :)
Just change definition

```
def ldap_get ( base_dn, filter, scope=LDAP::LDAP_SCOPE_SUBTREE, attrs=nil )
```

to

```
def ldap_get ( base_dn, filter, *param_array, attrs=nil )
scope = param_array.first || LDAP::LDAP_SCOPE_SUBTREE
```

scope will be now in array on its first place.
When you provide 3 arguments, then you will have assigned base_dn, filter and attrs and param_array will be []
When 4 and more arguments then param_array will be [argument1, or_more, and_more]

Downside is... it is unclear solution, really ugly. This is to answer that it is possible to ommit argument in the middle of function call in ruby :)

Another thing you have to do is to rewrite default value of scope.

Comment: This solutions is completely wrong. It is a syntax error to use a default value parameter (`attrs=nil`) after a splat (`*param_array`).

Comment: -1: Erik is correct. Causes a syntax error in irb 2.0.0p247. According to _The Ruby Programming Language_, in Ruby 1.8 the splat parameter had to be last except for an `&parameter`, but in Ruby 1.9 it could be followed by "ordinary parameters" as well. In neither case was a parameter with a default legal after a parameter with a splat.

Comment: Ruby Programming Language page 186/187 the splat is fine to use with methods. It has to be the last parameter in the method unless & is used.

Comment: So AndyG is right, the order needs to be: def ldap_get ( base_dn, filter, attrs=nil, *param_array)