# Why doesn't ruby support method overloading?

Tags: ruby

Instead of supporting method overloading Ruby overwrites existing methods. Can anyone explain why the language was designed this way?

Answer (score 177, accepted):

Method overloading can be achieved by declaring two methods with the same name and different signatures. These different signatures can be either,

1. Arguments with different data types, eg: `method(int a, int b) vs method(String a, String b)`
2. Variable number of arguments, eg: `method(a) vs method(a, b)`

We cannot achieve method overloading using the first way because there is no data type declaration in ruby(**dynamic typed language**). So the only way to define the above method is `def(a,b)`

With the second option, it might look like we can achieve method overloading, but we can't. Let say I have two methods with different number of arguments,

```
def method(a); end;
def method(a, b = true); end; # second argument has a default value

method(10)
# Now the method call can match the first one as well as the second one, 
# so here is the problem.
```

So ruby needs to maintain one method in the method look up chain with a unique name.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag's answer, buried far below, is definitely worth reading.

Comment: And @Derek Ekins' answer, buried even further, provides an alternative

Comment: Note to future rubyists ... FWIW you can do this with contracts gem https://egonschiele.github.io/contracts.ruby/#method-overloading

Comment: Here is the link to @Jörg W Mittag's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9380268/4880924

Answer (score 238):

"Overloading" is a term that simply doesn't even make sense in Ruby. It is basically a synonym for "static argument-based dispatch", but Ruby doesn't *have* static dispatch *at all*. So, the reason why Ruby doesn't support static dispatch based on the arguments, is because it doesn't support static dispatch, period. It doesn't support static dispatch of *any kind*, whether argument-based or otherwise.

Now, if you are *not* actually specifically asking about overloading, but maybe about *dynamic* argument-based dispatch, then the answer is: because Matz didn't implement it. Because nobody else bothered to propose it. Because nobody else bothered to implement it.

In general, dynamic argument-based dispatch in a language with optional arguments and variable-length argument lists, is *very* hard to get right, and even *harder* to keep it understandable. Even in languages with *static* argument-based dispatch and without optional arguments (like Java, for example), it is sometimes almost impossible to tell for a mere mortal, *which* overload is going to be picked.

In C#, you can actually encode *any* 3-SAT problem into overload resolution, which means that overload resolution in C# is NP-hard.

Now try that with *dynamic* dispatch, where you have the additional time dimension to keep in your head.

There are languages which dynamically dispatch based on all arguments of a procedure, as opposed to object-oriented languages, which only dispatch on the "hidden" zeroth `self` argument. Common Lisp, for example, dispatches on the dynamic types and even the dynamic values of all arguments. Clojure dispatches on an arbitrary function of all arguments (which BTW is extremely cool and extremely powerful).

But I don't know of any OO language with dynamic argument-based dispatch. Martin Odersky said that he *might* consider adding argument-based dispatch to Scala, but *only* if he can remove overloading at the same time *and* be backwards-compatible both with existing Scala code that uses overloading and compatible with Java (he especially mentioned Swing and AWT which play some extremely complex tricks exercising pretty much every nasty dark corner case of Java's rather complex overloading rules). I've had some ideas myself about adding argument-based dispatch to Ruby, but I never could figure out how to do it in a backwards-compatible manner.

Comment: This is the right answer. The accepted answer oversimplifies. C# DOES have named parameters and optional parameters and still implements overloading, so it's not as simple as "`def method(a, b = true)` won't work, therefore method overloading is impossible." It's not; it's just difficult. I found THIS answer really informative, however.

Comment: @tandrewnichols: just to give some idea how "difficult" overload resolution is in C# … it is possible to encode any 3-SAT problem as overload resolution in C# and have the compiler solve it at compile time, thus making overload resolution in C# NP-hard (3-SAT is known to be NP-complete). Now imagine having to do that not once per call site at compile time but once per method call for *every single method call* at runtime.

Comment: I know this is an old question and answer, but isn't it possible to let the compiler choose the overloading function to be used based on duck-typing the arguments for the functions that are called within the overloading function? Just wondering...

Comment: @JörgWMittag Could you include a link showing an encoding of a 3-SAT problem in the overload resolution mechanism?

Comment: @MrBones: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/03/28/lambda-expressions-vs-anonymous-methods-part-five.aspx

Comment: It doesn't look like "overloading" is a synonym for "static argument-based dispatch". Static argument-based dispatch is simply the most common implementation of overloading. Overloading is an implementation agnostic term meaning "same method name but different implementations in the same scope".

Comment: Elixir, another dynamic language, can elegantly handle method overloading: either using differing number of arguments, or using pattern matching. This is something that is rather common in the functional programming world, that is sadly missing in Ruby.

Answer (score 92):

I presume you are looking for the ability to do this:

```
def my_method(arg1)
..
end

def my_method(arg1, arg2)
..
end
```

Ruby supports this in a different way:

```
def my_method(*args)
  if args.length == 1
    #method 1
  else
    #method 2
  end
end
```

A common pattern is also to pass in options as a hash:

```
def my_method(options)
    if options[:arg1] and options[:arg2]
      #method 2
    elsif options[:arg1]
      #method 1
    end
end

my_method arg1: 'hello', arg2: 'world'
```

Comment: +1 for providing what many of us just want to know: how to work with a variable number of arguments in Ruby methods.

Comment: This answer might benefit from additional information about optional arguments. (And perhaps also named arguments, now that those are a thing.)

Answer (score 9):

This doesn't answer the question of why ruby doesn't have method overloading, but third-party libraries can provide it.

The [contracts.ruby](https://github.com/egonSchiele/contracts.ruby) library allows overloading. Example adapted from the tutorial:

```
class Factorial
  include Contracts

  Contract 1 => 1
  def fact(x)
    x
  end

  Contract Num => Num
  def fact(x)
    x * fact(x - 1)
  end
end

# try it out
Factorial.new.fact(5)  # => 120
```

Note that this is actually more powerful than Java's overloading, because you can specify values to match (e.g. `1`), not merely types.

You will see decreased performance using this though; you will have to run benchmarks to decide how much you can tolerate.

Comment: In real world applications with any kind of IO, you will have only 0.1-10% (depending on what kind of IO) slowdown.

Answer (score 8):

Method overloading makes sense in a language with static typing, where you can distinguish between different types of arguments

```
f(1)
f('foo')
f(true)
```

as well as between different number of arguments

```
f(1)
f(1, 'foo')
f(1, 'foo', true)
```

The first distinction does not exist in ruby. Ruby uses dynamic typing or "duck typing".  The second distinction can be handled by default arguments or by working with arguments:

```
def f(n, s = 'foo', flux_compensator = true)
   ...
end


def f(*args)
  case args.size
  when  
     ...
  when 2
    ...
  when 3
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with strong typing. Ruby *is* strongly typed, after all.

Answer (score 2):

there are already great answers on why side of the question. however, if anyone looking for other solutions checkout [functional-ruby](https://github.com/jdantonio/functional-ruby) gem which is inspired by Elixir [pattern matching](http://jerrydantonio.com/functional-ruby/Functional/PatternMatching.html) features.

```
 class Foo
   include Functional::PatternMatching

   ## Constructor Over loading
   defn(:initialize) { @name = 'baz' }
   defn(:initialize, _) {|name| @name = name.to_s }

   ## Method Overloading
   defn(:greet, :male) {
     puts "Hello, sir!"
   }

   defn(:greet, :female) {
     puts "Hello, ma'am!"
   }
 end

 foo = Foo.new or Foo.new('Bar')
 foo.greet(:male)   => "Hello, sir!"
 foo.greet(:female) => "Hello, ma'am!"
```

Answer (score 2):

I came across this nice interview with Yukihiro Matsumoto (aka. "Matz"), the creator of Ruby. Incidentally, he explains his reasoning and intention there. It is a good complement to @nkm's excellent exemplification of the problem. I have highlighted the parts that answer your question on *why* Ruby was designed that way:

> Orthogonal versus Harmonious
>
> Bill Venners: Dave Thomas also claimed that **if I ask you to add a
> feature that is orthogonal, you won't do it.** What you want is
> something that's harmonious. What does that mean?
>
> Yukihiro Matsumoto: I believe consistency and orthogonality are tools
> of design, not the primary goal in design.
>
> Bill Venners: **What does orthogonality mean in this context?**
>
> Yukihiro Matsumoto: An example of orthogonality is allowing any
> combination of small features or syntax. **For example, C++ supports
> both default parameter values for functions and overloading of
> function names based on parameters.** Both are good features to have in
> a language, but because they are orthogonal, you can apply both at the
> same time. The compiler knows how to apply both at the same time. If
> it's ambiguous, the compiler will flag an error. But if I look at the
> code, I need to apply the rule with my brain too. I need to guess how
> the compiler works. If I'm right, and I'm smart enough, it's no
> problem. But if I'm not smart enough, and I'm really not, **it causes
> confusion**. The result will be **unexpected** for an ordinary person. **This
> is an example of how orthogonality is bad.**

Source: "The Philosophy of Ruby", A Conversation with Yukihiro Matsumoto, Part I
by Bill Venners, September 29, 2003 at: https://www.artima.com/intv/ruby.html

Answer (score 1):

I often do the following structure :

```
def method(param)
    case param
    when String
         method_for_String(param)
    when Type1
         method_for_Type1(param)

    ...

    else
         #default implementation
    end
end
```

This allow the user of the object to use the clean and clear method_name : method
But if he want to optimise execution, he can directly call the correct method.

Also, it makes your test clearers and betters.

Answer (score 0):

Statically typed languages support method overloading, which involves their binding at compile time. Ruby, on the other hand, is a dynamically typed language and cannot support static binding at all. In languages with optional arguments and variable-length argument lists, it is also difficult to determine which method will be invoked during dynamic argument-based dispatch. Additionally, Ruby is implemented in C, which itself does not support method overloading.