# having multiple constructors in ruby

Tags: ruby, constructor, initialization

is there a way to have multiple “initialize” methods in ruby? 
For example:  one method excepting one  argument while another excepts three ?

Something like

```
 class One
  def initialize (a)
    puts a
  end
  def initialize_1 (a,b)
    puts a ,b 
  end
end
```

Comment: I agree with ramblex.  Also relevant - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373104/why-does-ruby-not-support-method-overloading.  If there is a specific problem you're trying to solve, you might try posting a more specific question as there may be a different way to go about it.

Comment: thanks, there is no specific problem im just trying to figure out the ins and outs of the  language.
I understand  that the answer is no  but  im still not sure how you get around that .

Comment: you could achieve the effect with `konstructor` gem https://github.com/snovity/konstructor, e.g. you would have just to declare `konstructor :initialize_1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`initialize` is actually not a constructor. You can indeed have two constructors.

```
class One
  singletonclass.class_eval{alias old_new :new}
  def self.new a
    puts a
    old_new
  end
  def self.new_1 a, b
    puts a, b
    old_new
  end
end
```

Comment: What does this buy you? Everything still funnels through the original new and the one initialize.  Might as well say `def self.new_1(a,b); new(a,b); end` without the complexity of the aliasing goo. It is common to have alternative constructors with different names that repackage their args into a general form for the base new.

Comment: we meet again , aren't  you are the guy who gave me such a lovely explanation of  how `self` works ?

Anyway this still complains 'wrong number of arguments' whenever I send it more then one argument .

Also im  not sure what this gets me ...