# Unable To access custom exceptions defined in a module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In My lib folder, I have a file image_helper_exception.rb. The path is `lib/dibs_exception/image_exception/image_helper_exception.rb`

In this file I have all my Image Exceptions defined

```
module DibsException
  module ImageException
     class ImageHelperException < Exception; end
     class InvalidEntityException < Exception; end
     class InvalidImageTypeException < Exception; end
     class InvalidImageVersionException < Exception; end
     class InvalidImageUrlException < Exception; end
     class ImageNotFoundException < Exception; end
  end
end
```

I raise applications elsewhere in my application when certain things are missing. The path to the file image_resize.rb where it is being used is helpers/image_resize.rb

The image_resize.rb looks something like this.

```
module Helpers
  class ImageResize
    require 'RMagick'
    require 'aws/s3'
    require 'rvg/rvg'
    require 'mechanize'
    include Magick

    def initialize(abc)
       if abc
         raise DibsException::ImageException::InvalidEntityException.new("Entity is invalid.")
         #The above line raises a error 
         #NameError: uninitialized constant DibsException::ImageException::InvalidEntityException
       else
         raise DibsException::ImageException::ImageHelperException.new("ImageHelperException.")
         #The above line does not raise a error 
        end
    end

end
```

I would like to add lib gets loaded in application.rb.

I am not able to understand why(`Helpers::ImageResize.new(true)`) is raising this error : `NameError: uninitialized constant DibsException::ImageException::InvalidEntityException`

But this works fine as expected : `Helpers::ImageResize.new(false)`

Why is only the first class loaded. Can some one help ? require does not work.

Comment: Ruby does not support method overloading -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373104/why-does-ruby-not-support-method-overloading

Comment: I removed it. Overloading is not the issue here. Accessing the exception is.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby does not support function overloading.
second initialize overwrite the first one while parsing.
soo only the second function exists.

This should do the magic.

```
def initialize(xyz=nil)
       raise DibsException::ImageException::InvalidEntityException.new("Entity is invalid.") if(xyz.blank?)
       raise DibsException::ImageException::ImageHelperException.new("ImageHelperException.")
       #This line DOES NOT raise error like above. It works fine.
end
```

Comment: lib folder is autoloaded, so you need to create classes based on file name. for if you ask for ImageHelperException, it looks for file named, image_helper_exception.rb, same way it might look fir invalid_entity_exception.rb when you call InvalidEntityException.

Comment: Yes, that is a solution. I solved it using load('lib/dibs_exception/image_exception/image_helper_exception.rb'). Do you have some alternative ?