# method output is displayed twice

Tags: ruby, class, module

```
module M
    def meth
        p "M"
    end
end

class C
    def meth
        p "C"
    end
end

class D < C
    #include M
end


d = D.new
p d.meth
```

Hi, can you please explain why the result of this code in Ruby is:

```
"C" 
"C"
```

(**TWICE**, as you can see)? 
Also, why uncommenting the line in `class D` definition renders `"M"`, also **TWICE**?

This is about  calling method x in a class which inherits from another class with method x and mixes in a module which also contains method x.

I can **guess** the double display of `"M"` in the second case is owed to the call `d.meth`: `meth` is found in the superclass of `D` and also in the `module` that `D` includes, so maybe the module method meth overwrites `class C`'s method `meth`. And then, maybe both are executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `meth` method within class `C` will print the value `"C"` as it currently stands, and next, since you are using another `p` statement at the end when you call `p d.meth`, the value `"C"` is printed again. The net effect is 2 print calls being made, causing the output of  2`"C"` statements.

To avoid this, just do

```
d = D.new
d.meth
```

The thing to note is that [every method in ruby returns a value](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_methods.htm), so thats how `"C"` is available for printing the second time.

> Every method in Ruby returns a value by default. This returned value will be the value of the last statement.

Same goes for the case when you use `include M`, the definition for method `meth` within module `M` already has a print statement with it, and the return value is printed again.

As for your guess, no you are wrong - it doesn't happen because the method is called twice.
Ruby overwrites the earlier `meth` method inherited from "C" with the `meth` method of the the module. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9373104/1860929) for more on method overloading in ruby.

Comment: Ruby doesn't return a value by default.  It is what all methods do and as far as I know you can't change that.  So it isn't 'default' it is just a characteristic of Ruby methods.

Comment: @vgoff the text is quoted from the link I have used just above it. As for the `by default statement`, I think its a comparison on how other languages like python, C etc need an explicit return statement unlike ruby, which might not be what a newcomer to ruby would expect.

Comment: @vgoff FWIW, I myself had gotten pretty confused when I saw return values being used without return statements when I was a beginner in ruby.

Comment: It is good, just default carries some weight that it is meant to change given some condition.  At least when I see the word 'default'.  Had you been told while learning Ruby that it isn't default, that it is simply the characteristic of a method, perhaps there would have been no confusion.  It was one of the first things I was told about Ruby.

Comment: @vgoff I have learnt much of it on my own, and since I had a programming background in C/Python already, I was naive enough to assume a return was necessary :)

Answer (score 3):

The first `"C"` is printed by `C#meth`.

The second one is printed by `p d.meth`; The return value of the `p "C"` is `"C"` which is returned to the caller of the `meth`.

Just calling `d.meth` without `p` will print only once.