# Why can't JRuby use my Java method whose parameter is a RubyArray when it is overloaded?

Tags: java, ruby, jruby

Have a Java class with an overloaded method:

```
public void test(float x) {

}

public void test(RubyArray array) {

}
```

In Ruby,

```
object.test(1.0)
```

Works fine. However:

```
object.test([1.0,2.0])
```

Will crash with the message:

```
org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (NameError) no method 'test' for arguments (org.jruby.RubyArray) on Java::MyNamespace::MyClass
  available overloads:
    (org.jruby.RubyArray)
    (int)
```

But, as you can see, that doesn't make any sense. It is telling me that there is no method for my argument of type `RubyArray`, and then it promptly tells me that there is an available overload for arguments of type `RubyArray`.

Interestingly, **this works fine if you remove the `(int)` overload**, that is, it works if the method that accepts `RubyArray` has no other overloads.

I have created many overloaded Java methods and used them in Ruby before, so I am guessing that the problem is related mainly to the `RubyArray` argument itself - although I don't see the issue.

Why is that? What am I doing wrong here?

---

I am using `JRuby 1.7.11`, building for what I think is `Java SE 6` on Eclipse Kepler for Mac.

---

To make it easier to test, you can run the following two programs:

**This works:**

```
import javax.script.*;

import org.jruby.RubyArray;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException, NoSuchMethodException {
        Main app = new Main();
    }
    public Main() throws ScriptException, NoSuchMethodException {
        ScriptEngine jruby = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("jruby");
        jruby.eval("include Java;\n" + "def start(main) main.test([1,2,3]); end");
        Invocable invocable = (Invocable)jruby;
        invocable.invokeFunction("start",this);
    }
    public void test(RubyArray array) {
        System.out.println(array);
    }
}
```

**This doesn't work:**

```
import javax.script.*;

import org.jruby.RubyArray;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException, NoSuchMethodException {
        Main app = new Main();
    }
    public Main() throws ScriptException, NoSuchMethodException {
        ScriptEngine jruby = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("jruby");
        jruby.eval("include Java;\n" + "def start(main) main.test([1,2,3]); end");
        Invocable invocable = (Invocable)jruby;
        invocable.invokeFunction("start",this);
    }
    public void test(int x) {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
    public void test(RubyArray array) {
        System.out.println(array);
    }
}
```

Comment: @kares: Yeah, the problem must be RubyArray. But I wonder why.

Comment: my previous edit has not been included thus a new comment: this would work with a `java.util.List` parameter ... I personally do thing it's a flaw in the resolution logic and would report this one (as a feature request) on https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues ... if you wonder why you'll need to dig into the Java support part of the sources

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because in Ruby you can't overload a method with the same number of arguments because there is no data type declaration.  You can only overload methods with different numbers of arguments: `public void test(int x)` vs `public void test(RubyArray arr, int x)`

So when you call the test-method it flips out and it just takes the first method (don't know how or why it searches or finds the one with the int-param).

Also see this answer: [Why doesn't ruby support method overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373104/why-does-ruby-not-support-method-overloading#answer-9373811)

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the type by using java_send (method name symbol), (array of types), *args, e.g.:

```
object.java_send :test, [RubyArray], [1.0,2.0]
```

For multiple args not sending an array, btw, it would look like this example from [CallingJavaFromJRuby](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/CallingJavaFromJRuby):

```
list.java_send :add, [Java::int, java.lang.Object], 0, 'foo'
```