# Unknown argument when call a function in another function

Tags: ruby

In my module, I defined two functions have the **same name** but **different number of arguments**.

```
module MyMod
 def self.doTask(name:, age:)
    doTask(name: "John", age: 30, career: "Teacher")
 end

 def self.doTask(name:, age:, career:)
   puts "name:#{name}, age:#{age}, career:#{career}"
 end
end
```

As you see above, in `doTask`, I just call `doTask`.

In another Ruby file, I call the `doTask` by:

```
MyMod.doTask(name:"Kate", age: 28)
```

But I get runtime error:

```
unknown keyword: career (ArgumentError)
```

Why?

Comment: When you're calling the method you're actually passing it a single hash as an argument, just so you know.

Comment: @sagarpandya82 no. This is keyword arguments. See https://robots.thoughtbot.com/ruby-2-keyword-arguments

Comment: @pascalbetz ah, thanks.

Comment: "I defined two functions have the same name" – No, you didn't. First off, you didn't define functions, you defined *methods*, that's an extremely important distinction. Ruby doesn't have functions. Second, you defined a method, then you defined it again, overwriting the previous definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby does not have method overloading. You can not have multiple methods with the same name.

One solution would be to use a the three argument version of the method and add a default value for the `:career` argument.

```
module MyMod
  def self.doTask(name:, age:, career: "Teacher")
    puts "name:#{name}, age:#{age}, career:#{career}"
  end
end
MyMod.doTask(name:"Kate", age: 28)
MyMod.doTask(name:"Kate", age: 28, career: 'Teacher')
MyMod.doTask(name:"Kate", age: 28, career: 'Mechanic')
```

Comment: Could you please provide some code just to be clear? Thanks

Comment: nice! exactly what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby doesn't support method overloading (2 methods with the same name and different parameters) so your second method definition with the `career` parameter is *replacing* the first method definition.

You can provide a default value for the optional parameter like this:

```
def self.doTask(name:, age:, career: 'Employee')
 puts "name:#{name}, age:#{age}, career:#{career}"
end
```

and then `career` will have the value "Employee" if not specified.

or default to `nil` and include some logic in the method body to handle

```
def self.doTask(name:, age:, career: nil)
  unless career.nil?
    # doTask with career
  else
    # doTask without career
  end
end
```

If you're coming to Ruby from another language like Java or C# then there's some great insight into why the equivalent behaviour doesn't exist in Ruby in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9380268/63034).